# Is there an overview of current resource usage in a GCP region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When a container cluster was created on GCP in the morning it took less than 10 minutes until it was created. Now, after more than half an hour the cluster is still not created. It turned out that the resources in a certain zone were insufficient. How to check whether there are enough resources in a GCP zone before creating for example a kubernetes cluster?

```
Instance 'X' creation failed: The zone 'projects/Y/zones/Z' does not have
enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone,
or try again later.
```

After choosing another zone and deploying the cluster took less than 4 minutes to deploy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [page indicates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/) something about regions and zones, but does not show any resource usage. I think that the resource usage of a zone is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is, if there is insufficient resource, it just throws error saying to choose another region but have never taken more than 5min to live cluster.